# Does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(p^{\frac{(k-1)k}{2}}-p^{\frac{(k+1)k}{2}})$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(p^{\frac{(k-1)k}{2}}-p^{\frac{(k+1)k}{2}})$$
$$ p\in\mathbb{R}|0{\leq}p<1$$
converse, and if so, to what function?

Comment: I don't know if this is of much help, but numerically this series seems to be the same as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^{\frac{(k+1)k}{2}}$, for all $0<p<1$.

Comment: With @Carl's simplification this returns a [theta function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28p%5E%28%28k%5E2%2bk%29/2%29,k=0..infinity%29).

Comment: Ilya: no, I mean that your series is numerically equal to the one I posted above. Another way to write the sum I posted is, as @Raymond mentioned, as a theta function $\vartheta_2(0,\sqrt{p})/2p^{1/8}$.

Comment: @CarlNajafi, the terms look like they should telescope to what you state.

Comment: @vonbrand: Yes, see Raymond's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's simplify your expression to get Carl Najafi's expression :

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\left(p^{\frac{(k-1)k}{2}}-p^{\frac{(k+1)k}{2}}\right)&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\;p^{\frac{(k-1/2)^2}2-\frac 18}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\;p^{\frac{(k+1/2)^2}2-\frac 18}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)\;p^{\frac{(k+1/2)^2}2-\frac 18}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\;p^{\frac{(k+1/2)^2}2-\frac 18}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\;p^{\frac{(k+1/2)^2}2-\frac 18}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\;p^{\frac{k(k+1)}2}\\
\end{align}
Proving Carl's claim.

After that you'll simply have to use the definition of the [second theta function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20.2#E2)
$$\theta_2(0,\sqrt{p})=2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\;\sqrt{p}^{(k+1/2)^2}$$
to get the [Alpha result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28p%5E%28%28k%5E2%2bk%29/2%29,k=0..infinity%29)  (since $\sqrt{p}^{1/4}=\sqrt[8]{p}$) :
$$\frac {\theta_2(0,\sqrt{p})}{2\;\sqrt[8]{p}}\quad\text{for}\ 0<p<1$$

Comment: Thanks @Mhenni even if at least half of the credit belongs to Carl Najafi !